# How to override animation when entering in PIP mode in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

My `PIPActivity` has only one image view and I am entering in PIP mode in `onCreate()` i.e `PIPActivity` is there only to show image in PIP mode. Now when I am starting `PIPActivity` there is some animation that slowly transitions into PIP mode. During this transition, the image is getting stretched weirdly. To avoid this how can stop the animation when entering PIP mode?
I have already tried

- In onCreate() calling overridePendingTransition(0, 0).
- Adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` while launching activity.
- Setting `<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` in activity theme.

Comment: Have you tried another image? Can you provide screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [ActivityOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions) and its various methods.

- [makeCustomAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions#makeCustomAnimation(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int))

> Create an ActivityOptions specifying a custom animation to run when the activity is displayed.

```java
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(MainActivity.this, 0, 0);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Or by using [setExitTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setExitTransition(android.transition.Transition)) and/or [setSharedElementExitTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setSharedElementExitTransition(android.transition.Transition)).

```java
getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);

//These functions define the exit transition for the calling activity.
getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(null);

setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
```

**NOTE**

Implement one of these in a launcher activity and **NOT** in PIPActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method and implement it on launcher activity:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(null);
setContentView(R.layout.mainActivity);
```